# Using javascript's replace with wildcard to change width attribute inside string

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I'm trying to use `.replace('width=".*"', 'width="100"')`, since `width` could be anything in the original `string`. But at the moment that does not change anything.

https://jsfiddle.net/bobbyrne01/8p404z5t/

html

```
<div id="1"></div><br/>
<div id="2"></div>
```

javascript

```
var fullURL = '<iframe class="embedly-embed" src="https://cdn.embedly.com/widgets/media.html?src=https%3A%2F%2Fi.imgur.com%2F…key=2aa3c4d5f3de4f5b9120b660ad850dc9&amp;type=video%2Fmp4&amp;schema=imgur" width="406" height="720" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen&gt;&lt;/iframe>';

document.getElementById('1').textContent = fullURL;

var moddedURL = fullURL.replace('width=".*"', 'width="100"');
document.getElementById('2').textContent = moddedURL;
```

result ..

```
<iframe class="embedly-embed" src="https://cdn.embedly.com/widgets/media.html?src=https%3A%2F%2Fi.imgur.com%2F…key=2aa3c4d5f3de4f5b9120b660ad850dc9&amp;type=video%2Fmp4&amp;schema=imgur" width="406" height="720" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen&gt;&lt;/iframe>

<iframe class="embedly-embed" src="https://cdn.embedly.com/widgets/media.html?src=https%3A%2F%2Fi.imgur.com%2F…key=2aa3c4d5f3de4f5b9120b660ad850dc9&amp;type=video%2Fmp4&amp;schema=imgur" width="406" height="720" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen&gt;&lt;/iframe>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you need to use wildcards, then you need to use Regular Expression, like this

```
var moddedURL = fullURL.replace(/width=".*?"/, 'width="100"');
```

Here, we use `/width=".*?"/`, which is a Regular Expression, and it means that match any string of the pattern `width="` followed any character which occurs zero or more times, till we see the first `"`.

**Note:** `.*` is actually greedy. If we don't use `?` after that, it will match everything in the string till the last `"`. That is why we explicitly make it non-greedy by using `?` and it will stop matching at the first occurrence of `"` following it.

---

In fact, you know that it will be numbers only. So you can make it match strictly like this

```
var moddedURL = fullURL.replace(/width="\d*"/, 'width="100"');
```

Now, it will match zero or more numeric digits, instead of any characters. Now we don't use `?` modifier because, the moment it finds a character which is not a digit, RegEx engine will stop matching. So we don't have to worry much about greedy matching here, unless your string will have whitespaces around the number.

Comment: @Rajesh `\d` matches a single digit, the expression `\d*` matches zero or more `\d`s occurring continuously. For example, `"9"` will be matched by `"\d"`, but not `"999"`.